# Try and Catch with Throws

Tags: java

So I came across this in our code, and I was wondering what the implication would be.

Java code:

```
public object name(Connection connection) throws SQLException 
{
   try {
        //something
        }

    catch (Exception e) {
        //something
        }
}
```

So my question is does anyone know if in the following case, will a SQLException be thrown and any other exception be caught?

Comment: It can only be thrown inside the `catch` block, all exceptions throwns inside the `try` will be caught.

Comment: Any Exception that is a subclass of `Exception` will be caught. If the catch block executes code that throws the SQLException, it will be propagated to the client.

Comment: Please provide a more clear/specific title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
throws SQLException
```

has no implications on this:

```
try {
    //something
}
catch (Exception e) {
    //something
}
```

The two constructs "don't know about each other".

The `throws` clause declares that the method as a whole *may* throw `SQLException`, but since your try-catch block catches any and all `SQLException`s, the method will probably not excercise that option. If your wish is to propagate the `SQLException`s, but catch and handle others, you may consider writing

```
try {
  // something
} catch (SQLException e)  { throw e; }
} catch (Exception e) { /* something */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the catch block doesn't throw a SQLException and if nothing outside the try-catch block does throw a SQLException, then no, this implementation does not throw a SQLException.

It's still valid to declare the SQLException in the signature in some cases, eg. if you want give subclasses which override this method the possiblity to throw a SQLException.

Answer (score 0):

try and catch blocks allow you to override the default error behavior for a set of program statements. If any statement in a try block generates an error, program control goes immediately to the catch block, which contains your error handling statements.

Answer (score 0):

All depends on `//something`

```
public object name(Connection connection) throws SQLException 
{
   try {
        //something1
        }

    catch (Exception e) {
        //something
        }
    //something2

}
```

If `//something1` is a cause of  `SQLException`  then it will be catched in `catch` (//something) bolck

If `//something2` is a cause of  `SQLException`  then it will thrown to the caller of `name()`

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void methodName(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            ...
            // This SQLException will be caught by the catch block
            throw new SQLException();
            ...
            // This OtherException will be caught by the catch block
            // as OtherException extends Exception
            throw new OtherException();
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
            // This SQLException will be thrown by the method
            throw new SQLException();
            ...
            // This will cause a compile error as methodName
            // throws SQLException but not OtherException or
            // the more generic Exception
            throw new OtherException();
            ...
        }
    }
```